# The best way resolve "fromJson" function in child class. DART language

Tags: dart

I have a problem with JSON convert in child class in dart. For example:

```
class Person {
   String firstName;
   String lastName;

   Person({
     this.firstName,
     this.lastName
   })

   factory Person.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
     return Person()
       ..firstName = json['firstName']
       ..lastName = json['firstName'];
   }
}

class User extends Person {
  String token;

  User({
    this.token
  });

   factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
     return User()
       ..token = json['token']

       // The problem is here. I need dublicate code to fill parent
       // class properties as first & last name of person:

       ..firstName = json['firstName']
       ..lastName = json['firstName'];
   }
}
```

My question is how to avoid code dublication in this case?
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a method on your base class that takes in the `Map<String, dynamic>` and populates the fields on itself, then call that from the subclass. However, I'd really recommend using something like [json_serializable](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable) to generate this code for you instead. It adds an additional step (you need to run `pub run build_runner build` or `pub run build_runner watch` to have the code re-generated) but it avoids you having to hand-write all of this.